# In blender, with do I get line on the edge of an object which should be transparent?

Tags: tree, png, blender

In blender 3.5, I'm trying to create a simple tree object which I can repurpose for different trees.

I've created a very thin boxes and arranged them into a star and them applied a UV map and png to create a tree.

The process has work well except I can see the edges of the boxes. In the UV map these edges are on a transparent region of the png. So I shouldn't be able to see them.

[image: my tree looks like this]

Any ideas how to remove the edges?

New to blender, just used steps in description above.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, in Wireframe mode, you can see all the vertices and edges so it is not incorrect when you are being displayed the edges, they are meant to be there. Just don't worry about them and keep on with your work.

However, if they cause trouble in the production, maybe just delete the face fill(not recommended) or make them transparent in the UV mapping as you did.